# How to detect keystrokes on another application in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Another question for today, sorry. My question is how to detect keystrokes on another application or on the desktop. For example, making hotkeys for an app, like a search engine. Or adding a keystrokes display in a video game. Thanks, Bye

Comment: Do you want them for a specific application, or just detect keypresses globally?  For global, do a search for "low level keyboard hook" and "WH_KEYBOARD_LL".  For hotkeys specifically, though, you'd use the RegisterHotKey() API.

Comment: Ok, so the API allows me to detect the keystroke anywhere, right?

Comment: The program just displays the keys being clicked. I have tried using the `E.keycode` function but no luck.

Comment: Anything with `e.keycode` is only going to capture keystrokes while YOUR application is in focus.  You need to use either the global hook or the hotkey approach.  These are not trivial things.

Comment: Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61177211/5162073) showing how to setup hotkeys.